# User icons on homepage are distracting

Tags: discussion, design, profile-picture, homepage

User profile icons are among the most colorful and varied elements on the homepage.

They draw attention to themselves but don't add value or readability.

Displaying icons there encourages users to make more attention-grabbing icons to draw viewers to their questions or profiles.

I suggest showing user names without an icon.

Comment: @Luuklag I didn't see anything there about user profile icons?  Did I miss it, or are you suggesting I post there?

Comment: and get rid of the collective trophies

Comment: The display of user icons is because of those changes, if you have feedback to those changes, add them as an answer there.